# Associative property for matrix and vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $a$,$b$ be $p \times 1$ vector, $A$, $B$ be $m\times n$ and $n \times k$ matrices, respectively, where $p,m,n,k$ are not equal.

I'm wondering if there is any way to construct $C$ and $D$, such that
$$(a'b)AB = CD,$$
where $C$ only depends on $a$ and $A$, while $D$ only depends on $b$ and $B$?

(I'm thinking about using Kronecker product or vectorization to manipulate the above equation, but don't really have a solution.)

Comment: How do $C$ and $D$ depends on $a,A,b,B$?

Comment: I want to find some way to construct $C$ as some operation between $a$ and $A$, and $D$ as some operation between $b$ with $B$, which is exactly what I'm struggling with.